# Objective-C how to define static parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new at Objective-C. I want to use global parameters like in C/C++

```
#define PARAM_1 1
```

How could I do this in Objective-C

Comment: Yes you can. It completely valid.

Comment: You'd use `#define PARAM_1 1`.  Objective-C *is* C.

Comment: To be more general, you can use `#define`, you can use an `enum`, you can use initialized `static` variables.  All the things you can do in regular C.  (And each has it's advantages and disadvantage -- there's no "perfect" solution.)

Comment: You can also, of course, use a method (instance method or class method) that returns a constant.

Answer (score 2):

The same way.

Objective-C is a superset of C, so your define is perfectly valid.

**edited following comment**

Rather than a define, which just performs textual substitution, you could use a static variable instead:

```
static NSNumber const * retrieveFriendRequestNumber = nil;
```

Which you can initialise in the class's initialiser method

```
+ (void)initialize {
    retrieveFriendRequestNumber = @(2);
}
```

(Yes a bit long-winded, but an example of how to initialise a literal).

and then you can use it as:

```
[parameters setObject:retrieveFriendRequestNumber forKey:@"fcode"];
```

Alternatively, declare it as a static NSUInteger and convert it to an object when you use it:

```
static NSUInteger retrieveFriendRequest = 2;
```

And use it as:

```
[parameters setObject:@(retrieveFriendRequest) forKey:@"fcode"];
```

Comment: [parameters setObject:RETRIEVE_FRIEND_REQUESTS forKey:@"fcode"];

Comment: it gives an error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion

Comment: @zontragon What's this line of code? RETRIEVE_FRIEND_REQUESTS is not an object, I guess.

Comment: @Reformer, it's defined like this #define RETRIEVE_FRIEND_REQUESTS 2

Comment: `2` isn't an object. It's because of this, most Objective-C programmers prefer to define type safe static variables.

Comment: I'm able to define string static variable but not number. @Larme yes, it's worked

Comment: This won't compile because: Initializer element is not a compile-time constant. You should rather use NSInteger as a constant and then convert it to NSNumber: [parameters setObject@(retrieveFriendRequestNumber) forKey:@"fcode"]

Comment: Yeah, I know. I thought their was something hinky about it.

Comment: Given all the problems above maybe he'd be better off using `#define`. :)

Comment: Hot Licks: I think the approach with const NSInteger and then boxing it into NSNumber is better. In general, I find constants safer and more readable than #defines.

Comment: static NSInteger const RETRIEVE_FRIEND_REQUESTS = 2;

Comment: [parameters setObject:@(RETRIEVE_FRIEND_REQUESTS) forKey:@"fcode"];

Comment: I'm able to use NSInteger without convert it to NSNumber